# How to join with Eloquent?

Tags: php, database, orm, eloquent

I would like to do automatic join-grouping when selecting from an Eloquent model in Laravel.

Let's suppose I have these tables:

```
humans        pets 
------        ----
int id        int id
varchar name  varchar name
              varchar category  
              int owner_id
```

Populated with these values:

```
humans        pets
------        ----
1 Bob         1 Lucy Dog 1
2 Alice       2 Sadie Dog 1 
3 Eve         3 Buster Cat 2
              4 Sam Fish 2
```

Therefore, in my PHP I have these Models:

```
class Human extends Eloquent {
}

class Pet extends Eloquent {
}
```

And this is my wish:

```
function wish() {
   return Human::all()->magic()->toJson();
}
```

For this, I wish to get this exact output. What `magic()` should I put in?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "pets": [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Lucy", "category": "Dog"},
      {"id": 2, "name": "Sadie", "category": "Dog"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alice",
    "pets": [
      {"id": 3, "name": "Buster", "category": "Cat"},
      {"id": 4, "name": "Sam", "category": "Fish"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Eve",
    "pets": []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your magic is done in two steps:

```
class Human extends Eloquent {
    public function pets() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Pet');
    }
}
```

And for your query

```
function wish() {
   return Human::with('pets')->all()->toJson();
}
```

You can also include the `with` into your Model:

```
class Human extends Eloquent {
    protected $with = ['pets'];

    public function pets() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Pet');
    }
}
```

The documentation about this is available from here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships